# How can I call a native function from an android rosjava node?

Tags: rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I want to call a native function from my rosjava node which basically does some processing work and returns a variable of type double which is then finally published by the publisher. Can anyone please help me out?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/175401/how-can-i-call-a-native-function-from-an-android-rosjava-node?/) by [Arjav](https://answers.ros.org/users/18918/arjav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-06-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-06-30**:
The android documentation for the native function you're trying to call should probably tell you how to call it from Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@Arjav this is a general Android question, so Android documentation is probably the best place to look for the answer,

Try starting here: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/index.html. That should help you to bind a Java method to native code, and also to compile and link the native code into your app.

---

Originally posted by [jubeira](https://answers.ros.org/users/29146/jubeira/) with karma: 1054 on 2018-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0